# Localization problems with Xcode 10?

Tags: localization, xcode10, ios12, xliff

I am trying to localise my app with Xcode 10 for iOS 12 and I run into some problems:

1. I want to exclude some UI elements that don't need translation;
2. I want to handle formatted text in a more logical way.

There are some UI elements in my screen of which the text is to be set dynamically at runtime. For example, a label that shows progress. This label has some placeholder text (e.g. "Progress") that does not need to be translated. Still, it ends up in my XLIFF file after exporting the storyboard. (I understand that I can add a note for the translator, but with quite a few of such UI elements, it really pollutes the XLIFF files.)


So the question is: is there a way to indicate in my storyboard that this text does not need to be translated and can thus be omitted from the XLIFF file?

The second issue is with formatted text. I want to format the text strings to display in the progress label and I tried the following:

```
    let formattedText = String.localizedStringWithFormat("Checking credentials for user '%@'...", userName)
    label.text = NSLocalizedString(formattedText, comment: "Bla bla bla")
```

That compiles fine and also the exporter does not complain. Unfortunately, it does not end up in the XLIFF file. Well, it sometimes does: I have more such formatted strings and I have the feeling that only one ends up in my XLIFF file.

I then changed my code to:

```
    label.text = NSLocalizedString(String.localizedStringWithFormat("Checking credentials for user '%@'...", userName), comment: "Bla bla bla")
```

i.e. I replaced the parameter `formattedText` with the `String.localizedStringWithFormat(...)` function and then it seems to work. But I find the first construction a lot clearer and I cannot understand why this does not work.

(I also tried creating a `Localizable.strings` file and fill it up with `genstrings`; that gives me an error message on such constructions.)

Is this an Xcode problem or am I doing something wrong?